# Javascript UK Phone number beautifier

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an input of a random UK phone number ("015395 30612"). I would like to create a function let's say phoneBeautifier(string) {}, that will output the same string but make it look "Beautiful". For example, the output could be: +44 (0)1539 530612

Im so bad with regex, is there any alternative way?

Comment: Can you explain the format of the number? If one can validate, one can probably format it... not familiar with UK numbers.

Comment: +44 is the country code. While calling from outside the UK you subtract the 0. While calling from inside the UK, you know longer need the +44 but you need the 0 in front  01539 530612. 1539 I guess is the are code.

Comment: Try this for better control and utilities. It is based on Google's libphonenumber library. https://github.com/albeebe/phoneformat.js?files=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var phoneNumber="015395 30612";
function format(phoneNumber) {
    return phoneNumber.replace(/\s+/g, '').replace(/(.)(\d{4})(\d)/, '+44 ($1)$2 $3');
}
['015395 30612','01539530612'].forEach(function(phoneNumber){
   console.log(format(phoneNumber));
});
```

you can try format(..) method instead.this function support all your situations.

Comment: Thanks holi-java. It works! It seems to be a regex. As I said Im very bad at it. Is it possible for you to give me an explanation on how it works please?

Comment: Note that this works for the exact input in the question, but not for anything else, e.g. it won't do anything to "01539530612" without a space.

Comment: yes,the regex only support your question.and you not provide all the requirements.so it fails on on situations.

Comment: Im using randomuser.me API, and set the location as UK. So all the phone inputs will have the same format. So thats not gonna be an issue I guess. Thanks for your tip though.

Comment: please wait I'll give you a regex supports your whole problem.

Comment: I've edited my answer that supports all your situations.

Comment: @siam I'm not.you can run my code and compare yours,you will find different.I haven't replace last 5 digits.and you have did it.

Comment: It's my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```js
function phoneBeautifier(number) {
  return number.replace(/^(\d)(\d{5})\s*(\d{5})/, '+44 ($1)$2 $3');
}
var beautifulPN = phoneBeautifier("01539530612");
console.log(beautifulPN);
```